# Open Device Settings in iOS 8 and not app settings

Tags: facebook, ios8, settings, facebook-login

I have a Facebook login button in my app , and when an account is not present on the device , I show an alert asking the user to login through device settings

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Now , if the user logs in but doesn't grant permission and again clicks on the Fb login button , I show an alert saying " You have not granted permission" and again would want to take the user to the device settings screen.

[image]

But the above code in this case takes me to app settings and not device settings . Can anyone help ?

Using iOS 8

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

I there is app settings, "UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString" will direct you to app settings only. If app settings is not there, it will go the settings main screen.